# Rails 6: Zeitwerk::NameError doesn't load class from module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a file which looks like this

```
#app/services/account/authenticate/base.rb
module Account
  module Authenticate
    AuthenticateError = Class.new(StandardError)

    class Base < ::Account::Base
      def self.call(*attrs)
        raise NotImplementedError
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now when I will run the code from `rails c` I have an error

```
> ::Account::Authenticate::AuthenticateError
=> NameError (uninitialized constant Account::Authenticate::AuthenticateError)
> ::Account::Authenticate.constants
=> [:Base, :ViaToken]
```

So rails doesn't see AuthenticateError class. But when I will create a nested class from this folder like

```
=> Account::Authenticate::ViaToken
> ::Account::Authenticate.constants
=> [:Base, :AuthenticateError, :ViaToken]
```

AuthenticateError class is now visible

```
> ::Account::Authenticate::AuthenticateError
=> Account::Authenticate::AuthenticateError
```

The solution for this problem is to create a separate file authenticate_error.rb which will work from the beginning but this solution is not ideal for me. Is there any solution to preload all classes or smth?

(Ruby 2.6 with Rails 6.0.0.rc2)

Comment: Have you tried setting `config.eager_load = true` in `config/environments/development`?

Comment: @jvillian it doesn't work

Comment: Are you using spring, by chance?

Comment: @jvillian yes, spring and all rails server was stopped/restarted after changes

Comment: Did you `spring stop`?

Comment: @jvillian yes :)

Comment: I experienced this even without spring. However it only happens when my module is in a non-railsy directory and is nested. ie. I can add `config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'service_objects', '{*/}')]` and it will include everything in service_objects. I can also add modules to subdirectories in /app/models. However, the same does not work for files nested in a non-rails-directory.

Answer (score 39):

I experienced this same issue when deploying a Rails 6.0.2 application to an Ubuntu 18.04 server.

> Unable to load application: Zeitwerk::NameError: expected file /home/deploy/myapp/app/models/concerns/designation.rb to define constant Designation, but didn't

I found out that the issue was with **zeitwerk**. Zeitwerk is the new code loader engine used in Rails 6. It’s meant to be the new default for all Rails 6+ projects replacing the old **classic** engine. Zeitwerk provides the features of code autoloading, eager loading, and reloading.

**Here's how I solved it**:

Navigate to the `config/application.rb` file on your project.

Add this line within your application module to switch to `classic` mode for autoloading:

```
config.autoloader = :classic
```

Here's an example:

```
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 6.0

    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration can go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded after loading
    # the framework and any gems in your application.

    config.autoloader = :classic
  end
end
```

You can read up more on **zeitwerk** in this article: [Understanding Zeitwerk in Rails 6](https://medium.com/cedarcode/understanding-zeitwerk-in-rails-6-f168a9f09a1f)

Comment: Didn't quite work for me. I had to give up on `config.load_defaults 6.0` for now. I'm hoping the article and guides can get me up to speed on where I'm going wrong.

Comment: even i had to remove config.load_defaults 6.0 to make it work. Any help?

Answer (score 7):

updating a Rails app from 5.2 to 6.0 and also hit the Zeitwerk bump!

If you want to continue to use the autoloading mode you're currently using, avoiding Zeitwerk, then add this line to your application.rb file ([@PromisePreston answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57277351/rails-6-zeitwerknameerror-doesnt-load-class-from-module#:%7E:text=hope%20this%20helps-,Share,-Edit) and [Rails doc](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#project-structure))

```
config.autoloader = :classic
```

If you want to upgrade to Zeitwerk then a command to use is `bin/rails zeitwerk:check` (From this [guide article](https://ecommercefastlane.com/9-tips-tricks-to-help-you-enable-the-zeitwerk-autoloader-in-your-rails-app/)).

Scenario we hit closest to this particular question was where we had a file within a subfolder like this:

```
#presenters/submission_files/base.rb
module Presenters
  module SubmissionFiles
    class Base < Showtime::Presenter
      def method_call
        #code_here
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Removing an extra modules to have:

```
 #presenters/submission_files/base.rb
 module Presenters
   class SubmissionFiles::Base < Showtime::Presenter
      def method_call
        #code_here
      end
   end
 end
```

Then, when calling the method in other ruby files in the app use: `Presenters::SubmissionFiles::Base.method_call`

Answer (score 4):

`zeitwerk` follow `conventional file structure` which is able to load your project's classes and modules on demand (autoloading) as long as you follow it's rule.

```rb
# service/account/authenticate/base.rb
module Account
  module Authenticate
    puts "load service ....."
    AuthenticateError = Class.new(StandardError)

    class Base
    end
  end
end

::Account::Authenticate::AuthenticateError # uninitialized constant
::Account::Authenticate::Base # load service ....
::Account::Authenticate::AuthenticateError # OK
```

as you can see, the first time you attempt to reach the constant `AuthenticateError`, the log `load service ...` does not show, that because you don't play `zeitwerk` rule:

- whenever it gets a request to load the const `::Account::Authenticate::AuthenticateError`, first it'll check and return if that constant already loaded, otherwise it'll look for the file `/account/authenticate/authenticate_error.rb` which corresponding to the constant `::Account::Authenticate::AuthenticateError` to find that constant definition, but it could not find it.
- on step 2, when you call `::Account::Authenticate::Base`, it could find the file `/account/authenticate/base.rb` and load it, during this time, it's also load the constant `AuthenticateError` which is defined on that file, now we have the constant `::Account::Authenticate::AuthenticateError`, and of course, it's OK on step 3.

now let try to play with the `zeitwerk` rule, i create a file `/account/authenticate/authenticate_error.rb` as below

```rb
# service/account/authenticate/authenticate_error.rb
module Account
  module Authenticate
    puts "load error ....."
    AuthenticateError = Class.new(StandardError)
  end
end
```

and try to attempt that constant at the step 1

```rb
$ spring stop
$ rails c
> ::Account::Authenticate::AuthenticateError
load error .....
=> Account::Authenticate::AuthenticateError
```

it worked since `zeitwerk` found the file `account/authenticate/authenticate_error.rb`. (note that the file name `/____authenticate_error.rb` still work)

my thought: i think you could work safely with the constant `AuthenticateError` inside the module `::Account::Authenticate`, in case of you want to expose those error constants to outside, you could create file `/account/authenticate/error.rb`

```
# service/account/authenticate/error.rb
module Account
  module Authenticate
    module Error
     AuthenticateError = Class.new(StandardError)
    end
  end
end
```

then you could access `::Account::Authenticate::Error::AuthenticateError`, in my opinion, it even clearer than put `AuthenticateError` inside `base.rb`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by not trying to fight Rails 6. `Zeitwerk` autoloads certain expected folders, which includes app/models, app/controllers, app/helpers and others.

I created a folder `app/helpers` and moved my `services` folder into it.

That's it!