# Rails 6+, zeitwerk autoloader and namedspaced constants

Tags: autoload, ruby-on-rails-6, zeitwerk

The Rails 6+ default autoloader is zeitwerk, which seems like a great improvement over previous approaches.

However, zeitwork follows the convention for Rails projects that anything in `app/*` is autoloaded and doesn't need to be namespaced.

This works great for `app/models/user.rb` because you don't have to use `Models::User` but can just reference `User`.

However, I added my own `app/services` directory and I namespace my service objects as `Services::Users::Create`, which would map to `app/services/users/create.rb`.

Zeitwork is throwing errors that my class constants don't exist, since it is expecting `Users::Create` (without the `Services::` prefix).

Is there anyway to configure zeitwork to require the `Services::` namespace in these instances?  In my opinion, it is a much cleaner to read the code as `Services::Users::Create` and know that you're looking in the `app/services/users/create.rb` file.

If you just had `Users::Create`, an average Rails developer would probably look for the `app/models/users/create.rb` file.

I don't like the approach of naming it `Users::CreateService`, it just seems very inelegant to me.

I can't be the only one who uses conventions like this; has anyone else come across a solution?  I'm still going through all the zeitwerk documentation looking for a solution but haven't found one yet.

Answer (score 5):

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#having-app-in-the-autoload-paths

Some projects want something like app/api/base.rb to define API::Base, and add app to the autoload paths to accomplish that in classic mode. Since Rails adds all subdirectories of app to the autoload paths automatically, we have another situation in which there are nested root directories, so that setup no longer works. Similar principle we explained above with concerns.

If you want to keep that structure, you'll need to delete the subdirectory from the autoload paths in an initializer:

```
ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths.delete("#{Rails.root}/app/api")
```

Comment: According to docs mutating ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths is not recommended, the public interface to change autoload paths is config.autoload_paths https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoload-paths

Answer (score 0):

I needed something similar but for `integrations`. I also didn't want the class to be called `Integrations::Base` but instead `Integration::Base`.

I created a file `config/initializers/integrations.rb` with the following:

```
ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths.delete("#{Rails.root}/app/integrations")

autoloader = Rails.autoloaders.main
autoloader.push_dir(Rails.root.join("app"))
autoloader.inflector.inflect "integrations" => "Integration"
```

Then created `app/integrations/base.rb` with:

```
module Integration
  class Base
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Little late to the party here but had a very similar situation! Even named the folder the same thing "Services"

This seems to have helped add it to the auto loading path within the application.rb file:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/services/)
```

Then within the sub directory the module and class was defined like this:

#services/sub_folder/base.rb

```
module Services
  class SubFolder::Base
  end
end
```

I have a similar answer with more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69186825/5070253).

Then more general Zeitwerk resources and tips for updating [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69187185/5070253).