# Rails 6 expected file to define constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I just created my first Rails 6 project `ruby 2.7.0 rails 6.0.3`.
I have the following file:

```
#app\models\foo.rb

class Foo
  def initialize
  end

  def bar
   puts("Whoohoo!")
  end
end
```

From `rails console` I am trying to run:

```
foo = Foo.new
```

And I keep getting the error:

```
Zeitwerk::NameError (expected file <mypath>/app/models/foo.rb to define constant Foo, but didn't)
```

Coming from Rails 5 I'm lost as to what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: It seems a similar issue was asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57277351/rails-6-zeitwerknameerror-doesnt-load-class-from-module

Answer (score 1):

Can be that `puts("Whoohoo!)` missing a quote, but the syntax parser would get, so I'm assuming that is not the case.

You can call `ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths` in `rails console` to consult if your model it is actually being loaded.